# How to use `cplexAPI` to solve quadratic programs/linear programs with quadratic constraints?

Tags: r, cplex

I am trying to use `cplexAPI` to solve quadratic programs or linear programs with a quadratic constraint.

While it seems to be pretty straightforward to use `cplexAPI` to solve linear programs (with the vignette at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cplexAPI/vignettes/cplexAPI.pdf), it seems that using `cplexAPI` to solve quadratic programs or linear programs with a quadratic constraint is much more difficult. I tried to look over the package documentation, but I have no clue on how to do so.

Therefore, may I know how to use `cplexAPI` to solve quadratic programs or linear programs, or if there is any code samples for these two tasks?

In addition, the package `Rcplex` seems to be pretty similar, but its last update is already more than 5 years ago. So it would be really nice to know how the above two tasks can be done using `cplexAPI` in R. Thanks!

Comment: OR stack exchange might be a better place for you to have some answers on this question: https://or.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

with cplexAPI you may use [addQConstrCPLEX](https://rdrr.io/cran/cplexAPI/man/addQConstrCPLEX.html) to add quadratic constraints